# Why async and await in Razor Pages NET CORE

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am havin a course for .NET Core, and they learn us to use

```
public async Task OnGet()
{
}
```

and

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
{
    await database.SMTH.FindAsync()
}
```

why they are not using simple

```
public IActionResult OnGet();
```

and

```
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
}
```

This is the first time I have met this using async and await in .NET Core Razor Pages. And I dont know why they are doing it this way.
(I know what async methods are.)
Thank you.

Comment: I believe the best you can do is read through what async/await does and how it works. It will answer for your question. Or, if not, then you can specify more your question.

Comment: I know what async methods are. I just dont get the context of using it here while loading pages (get or post request)

Comment: The Razor code compiles to C# and from this point on it gets the same async/await goodnes from .Net Core Framework as other C# code. If the code would be as you mentioned than it wouldn't take advantage on async/await rather it would use a thread until it finishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods you posted are [handler methods](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods) that execute when pages are loaded, based on the HTTP verb that was used to make the request. If you have asynchronous code to run e.g.to get data from a database, when your page loads, you need to place that in an asynchronous handler method - one that has the `async` operator and returns a `Task` or `Task<T>`.